# Нужно изменить переменную в наследуемом классе Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп, наследование, 2d

я Столкнулся с следующей проблемой: Мне нужно в дочернем классе **Movement** изменить переменную **bossPositionY** на числа из массива **YposForBoss**[image: Код]

Как это можно сделать? Код ниже

[image: Код]

Comment: с таким вопросом срочно закрывайте Юнити, пока не приобрели плохих привычек. И откройте книги по самым начальным началам и основным основам языка C#

Comment: Одно имеет тип float, другое - массив..... спрашивается: какого хряка тут что-то изменять?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский нынче детишки читать совсем не умеют...давно разучились. юТУП - их учитель.

Comment: Я спросил как можно ИЗМЕНИТЬ, а не что мне следует делать. К чему токсичность? я задал конкретный вопрос, ожидая получить конкретный ответ.

Comment: Задать вопрос в виде "как можно поменять молоток на рубанок, чтобы было удобно пилить хлеб" в ожидании получить конкретный ответ - очень глупо. С учётом того, что у тебя **очевидно** опыта катастрофически нет, то ты не можешь оценить адекватно, на сколько твой вопрос и просьба - бессмысленны.  А на сколько вопрос нелепый, ты можешь узнать банально почитав азы ЯП..... А если это тебе не хочется это делать, тогда вообще зачем разработкой занимаешься...? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: При текущем подходе думаю проще описать что хочется сделать, для чего, какова цель. Может быть знающие помогут именно выработать правильный подход, а не потакать хотелкам человека, который непонимает ничего и хочет сапоги через голову надевать.......... ЗЫ: код надо прикладывать текстом, а не картинками, в которых ничего не видно, особенно если смотреть с мобилки

Comment: Опыт приобретается благодаря практике, и мне не понятно, хоть я сам довольно просто решил свою проблему, Зачем писать своё личное мнение вместо какой-то действительно полезной инфы. Ты пишешь "бессмысленный вопрос" и прочее, так и не объясняя почему это так. Если у тебя нет либо желания или полезной инфы, то не вижу смысла писать всё выше написанyое тобой. Я лишь в процессе обучения. И да, я читаю книги о C# и об основах ООП

Comment: Судя по твоему вопросу - не читаешь. Иначе бы не задавал такой глупый вопрос

Answer (score -2):

```
 //доп класс
    public class BaseMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        protected float bossPositionY;
    }
    //основ класс
    public class BossMovement : BaseMovement
    {
        protected string[] YposForBoss;
        public string[] GetYposForBoss()
        {
            return YposForBoss;
        }
    }
    //дочерн класс
    public class Movement : BossMovement
    {
        private void GetData()
        {
             string[] yposArray = GetYposForBoss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: боже, почему всё так?